# Desconsiderar autenticação HTTP para determinada URL

Tags: cakephp, htaccess, mod-rewrite, htpasswd

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em **CakePHP 2**, mas acredito que a questão não tenha tanto envolvimento com o framework em si, apenas citando para contextualizar.

Sendo esta aplicação privada, basicamente um *webservice* para acesso aos dados com um aplicativo móvel, eu restringi o acesso utilizando autenticação *basic HTTP* do próprio **Apache** no arquivo `.htaccess`.

Existe o caminho **físico** para `files/photos` que eu quero acesso livre, então incluí esta exceção ficando assim:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Meu webservice"
AuthUserFile /foo/bar/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

SetEnvIf Request_URI "files/photos/" allow

Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy any
```

Funciona perfeitamente, restringindo todo o acesso ao *webservice* com exceção do diretório indicado. Agora eu preciso restringir um novo acesso mas desta vez não é uma URL apontando para um caminho físico e sim "virtual", já que o framework (*MVC-like*) utiliza o `mod_rewrite` para fazer a reescrita das URLs.

Apenas adicionando a linha abaixo não obtive sucesso, ainda é solicitado usuário e senha.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "users/confirmation/" allow
```

Não sei se o problema passa pelo fato da utilização da reescrita de URLs, mas considerando que um caminho físico eu obtive sucesso e o outro não, imagino que faça algum sentido minha dúvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido da seguinte forma: os dois caminhos que serão ignorados pela autenticação HTTP do Apache, tanto o físico quanto o que está aplicado a reescrita de URL pelo `mod_rewrite` ficam assim:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "files/photos/" noauth=1
SetEnvIf Request_URI "users/confirmation/*" noauth=1
```

Aqui vale lembrar que só troquei o nome da variável `allow` para `noauth` para melhor entendimento do código, sendo uma variável é possível utilizar qualquer nome.

Enfim, bastou adicionar mais uma linha indicando esta variável de ambiente com o prefixo `REDIRECT_`:

```
Allow from env=REDIRECT_noauth
```

Pronto, funcionou para os dois casos.